# SVG length of text throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, svg, batik

I use Batik to create a SVG Document. I create a text element and want to get it's width. However I get a NPE:

```
Element composite = container.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(SVGUtility.SVG_NS, SVGConstants.SVG_G_TAG);
SVGOMTextElement txt = (SVGOMTextElement) parent.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(SVGUtility.SVG_NS, SVGConstants.SVG_TEXT_TAG);
txt.setTextContent("lorem");
composite.appendChild(txt);
txt.getComputedTextLength();

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGTextContentSupport.getComputedTextLength(SVGTextContentSupport.java:240)
at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMTextContentElement.getComputedTextLength(SVGOMTextContentElement.java:186)
```

the NPE is because the context is null here:

```
final SVGTextContent context = (SVGTextContent)svgelt.getSVGContext();
```

Is there a way to assign the correct context before?

Comment: we create the SVG DOM and display it in the browser. So it is not SWING/SWT specific

Comment: OK so the other thing is that you need to add the text to the DOM via appendChild or the like before measuring it.

Comment: updated my code, but it does not work either

Comment: the NPE is because the context is null: final SVGTextContent context = (SVGTextContent)svgelt.getSVGContext();  do you know how I can get the context?

Comment: @matthias I'd love to have an answer to this - why does getSVGContext() return null?